# How to obtain the folder name of a music file (or any file) dynamically

Tags: java, android, directory, android-music-player

I have been searching on how to get the name of a folder (in internal sd card) containing my music files from the device but all the examples I saw was about how to get the file name not the folder. How can I write a code which is actually dynamic, meaning it does not matter what the file path is, it always gets the folder (directory) name of a file.

In my application I'm trying to get the folder name of my music files and save it as a string, using a cursor I did as follows

```
 ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

            if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int pathColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);


                counter = 0;
                do {
                    String thisPath = musicCursor.getString(pathColumn);
                    //String folderName = ???

                } while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
```

So this gives me the path which is something like this:
/storage/emulated/0/folderName/fileName.ext

I would be thankful if someone could tell me how to get the folderName.
Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create `new File(thisPath)` and invoke [`getParent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29) and call [`getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29) on it

Comment: so do you mean like getParent().getName()?, cause it's not working like that!!

Comment: `getParent()` returns `String` so you need to convert it to `File` again, like `new File(new File(thisPath).getParent()).getName()`

Comment: oh but I want to save as a string so just leave it like .getParent() yeah?

Comment: `getparent()` returns _The pathname string of the parent directory named by this abstract pathname, or null if this pathname does not name a parent_ , see my  comment above

Answer (score 1):

Parse it as file.

```
File f = new File(thisPath);
f.getParent();
```